# How to disable intellisense for perfectly typed word ? (VS 2015 & Resharper 10.0.2)

Tags: intellisense

I have checked on numerous questions here on stack overflow & web but I cannot find a solution to intellisense (and resharper 10.0.2) auto completing of a word I typed correctly in Visual Studio (2015).

For example: on a new project I type the text 'require'. On finishing the 'e' Intellisense appears with a few suggestions.  The next thing I want/type is a '('.  Intellisense puts requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers() on the screen.

I don't have to go back and delete this intellisense suggestion or press Escape every time I type I word I want to keep.

Is there anyway I can get Intellisense/Resharper to require a key (e.g tab) as confirmation for something in the drop down box ? Its ridiculous to have everything come out of the drop down suggestion box as standard.

Autocompletion is ok near the end of a project when a lot of the variable & references are already referenced and it gets pretty accurate but a lot of the time that is not the case.